# AssemblyCleanup() after test fail/exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm running a few unit tests that requires a connection to the database. When my test project get initialized, a snapshot of the database is created, and when tests are done the database gets restored back to the snapshot.

Here is the implementation:

```
[TestClass]
public static class AssemblyInitializer
{
    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
        var dbss = new DatabaseSnapshot(...);    
        dbss.CreateSnapshot();
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup()]
    public static void AssemblyCleanup()
    {
        var dbss = new DatabaseSnapshot(...);
        dbss.RevertDatabase();
    }
}
```

Now this all works, but my problem arise when I have a failing test or some exception. The AssemblyCleanup is of course not invoked, so how can I solve this problem? No matter what happens, the snapshot has to be restored. Is this possible?

Comment: In the unit test you can add code that will be executed when a test finishes. Perhaps look there? :)

Comment: @Oskar Isn't there something "assembly-wide" I can do? Otherwise I would have to do that for all the tests. It's possible, but I would like the other solution better.

Comment: I'm new in unit testing issues but I think using db in unit tests is not a best practice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Comment: I know, but thats not really the question here :-) This is for testing an ObjectContext (EF), which is hard to mock.

Comment: Perhaps use TransactionScope? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't do it this way.  Somebody might trip over the power cord.  Always copy a known-good copy of the database files and attach them.  Look in the documentation for the dbase engine you use how to attach.

Comment: You are right. Maybe I should invest more time in mocking the ObjectContext.

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption that AssemblyCleanup won't be invoked is wrong. Unless someone might "trip over the power cord" (as Hans suggested above), TestCleanup, ClassCleanup and AssemblyCleanup all execute regardless if there was an exception or not (or test failure).

Note that this is true as long as your test (or code under test) does't spawn new threads that might throw exceptions.

Bottom line: Hans solution is stonger, but for most cases, I find that AssemblyCleanup is good enough and more straight-forward.

Comment: This is wrong. `AssemblyCleanup` will NOT be called if there was an unhandled exception. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblycleanupattribute.aspx

Comment: I'm surprised to see this sentence in the documentation, but it either wrong or we both don't understand what exactly it refers to (I just tested it!). The only situation that it won't be called is if there's an exception inside the [AssemblyInitialize] method. Also, see [my blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arnona/2014/09/02/right-way-test-cleanup/) for my recommendation handling cleanup.